# Finding $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}x\left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^4\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}x\left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^4\,\mathrm dx$$I don't know how to solve this limit problem. I'm roughly clear about using the pinch theorem, but I haven't done it yet. Could somebody please tell me? Thanks!

Comment: \(pinch theorem\)

Comment: there's some formula like $\sum_{|n| \le N} e(n\theta) = \frac{\sin(N\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$. Something like that. I think that should be useful

Comment: I checked through W|A for values of $n$ as high as $n\sim 20000$ and it seems that the limit does exist and is equal to $\ln 2$. But at present I don't have a rigorous proof for the same.

Comment: After a lengthy semi-heuristic study I suspect the simple result $\lim = \log(2) \simeq 0.6931471805599453..$

Comment: Another way to reach the integral in Tianlalu's answer is as follows: Substituting $nx = u$ and writing $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$, we have
$$ \frac{1}{n^2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \frac{\sin^4(nx)}{\sin^4 x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\frac{n \pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^4 u}{u^3 \operatorname{sinc}^4(u/n)} \, \mathrm{d} u
\ \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\text{DCT}} \ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^4 u}{u^3} \, \mathrm{d} u, $$
where the convergence follows  from the dominated convergence together with the integrable dominating function $Cu^{-3}\sin^4 u$ for some constant $C > 0$.

Comment: Someone said *Jackson kernel*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^2\left(\frac1{\sin^4 x}-\frac1{x^4}\right)=\frac23,$$
for $x\in(0,\frac\pi 2)$, there is $C$ such that
$$\left|\frac{x\sin^4 nx}{\sin^4 x}-\frac{\sin^4 nx}{x^3}\right|\le \frac{C\sin^4 nx}{x}\le Cn.$$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}x\left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^4\, \mathrm dx&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\sin^4 nx}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{n\pi}2}\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^3}\, \mathrm dx\\
\text{(IBP)}\quad &= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\sin^3 x\cos x}{x^2}\, \mathrm dx\\
\text{(IBP)}\quad &= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{6\sin^2 x\cos^2 x-2\sin^4 x}{x}\, \mathrm dx\\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos 2x-\cos 4x}{x}\, \mathrm dx\\
\text{(Frullani)}\quad &=\ln 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

**Result**

Let

$$f(n) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} x \left(\frac{\sin (n x)}{\sin (x)}\right)^4 \, dx$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{f(n)}{n^2}=\log (2)\simeq 0.6931471805599453 ...$$

This result is in good agreement with the numerical estimate of the integral.

**Derivation**

This is more heuristic and not really strict. Maybe others can fill in the gaps.

We split the integral into equally spaced intervals, and observe $\sin(\pi x/n) \simeq \pi x/n$ for $n\to \infty$ and get

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(n)/n^2 =\lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(k)\tag{1}$$

where

$$a(k) = \int_{k-1}^k \pi ^2 s \left(\frac{\sin (\pi  s)}{\pi  s}\right)^4 \, ds$$

The first two values are

$$a(1) = \text{Ci}(2 \pi )-\text{Ci}(4 \pi )+\log (2)$$
$$a(2) = -\text{Ci}(-8 \pi )+\text{Ci}(-4 \pi )-\text{Ci}(2 \pi )+\text{Ci}(4 \pi )$$

and for $k \ge 3$

$$a(k) = -\text{Ci}(2 (k-1) \pi )+\text{Ci}(4 (k-1) \pi )-\text{Ci}(-4 k \pi )+\text{Ci}(-2 k \pi )$$

Here $\text{Ci}(z) = -\int_{-\infty }^z \frac{\cos (t)}{t} \, dt$ is the cosine integral.

The sum in $(1)$ telescopes and we are left with the announced result.

**Discussion**

My statement "the sum telescopes" is fairly bold.

In fact, the cancellation is like this

$$\text{Ci}(-4 \pi )-\text{Ci}(4 \pi )=i \pi$$
$$\text{Ci}(8 \pi )-\text{Ci}(-8 \pi )=-i \pi$$

see symmetry relations in http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf,   5.2.20, and the sum of these two lines is $0$.